# Creating a drop down list (formatted differently)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a drop-down menu that shows data of a customer
like their address of a customer when their name is selected on the list, how much they've paid etc.

The only thing is Ive spent a while looking on the internet and the only thing I can find is using data validation, but the data I have is not presented in line items.

For example, the address is listed as House name in one cell, Street address in the cell below, post code in the cell below, and I dont want to make them separate columns because i'd only have one line of data for each person, but would rather it be presented differently.

This is how i wanted each drop down select to be shown

[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the values in a new column and hide the Column Address